# Почему Safari рендерит фоновые SVG-картинки как растровые?

Tags: svg, background, safari

Сделал элементарную страницу с SVG-фигурой.

```css
    div {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background-image: url(https://svgshare.com/i/FJ_.svg);
      background-size: cover;
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Во всех браузерах эта фоновая картинка рендерится векторной, но Safari, как настольный, так и мобильный в iOS, делает ее растровой. Особенно это заметно, если увеличить изображение.

Выглядит так:

[image: background SVG in Safari]

Насколько я понял, Safari рендерит так эту картинку из-за примененных к фигуре эффектов, в данном случае тень и градиентная заливка.

Так вот, можно ли как-нибудь заставить его выводить это изображение векторным?

Comment: 1) «делает ее растровой» — это не так. 2) По [прямой ссылке](https://svgshare.com/i/FJ_.svg) Ваш SVG отображается корректно в Safari. 3) Поищите по фразе "svg blurry safari", может, найдете решение. Скорее всего, проблема в Вашем файле.

Comment: По прямой ссылке - да, но я говорю об использовании SVG в фоне блока. Взгляните еще раз, увеличив получившийся результат по кнопке Выполнить код. С файлом точно проблем нет, так как Safari так мылит абсолютно все SVG.

Comment: «Safari так мылит абсолютно все SVG» — это не так.

Comment: Так. Все SVG с тенями у объектов в фоне блоков.

Comment: «все SVG» — Вы так написали.